# What does this get mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> “Get on your hands and knees.” –– [learningyoga.com](http://www.learningyoga.com/poses/vinyasa.html)

I’m wondering if *get* above is a linking verb ([OLAD #11](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/get)) or an intransitive verb (# 18) that takes locative adverb. I guess if the prepositional phrase, *on your hands and knees*, denotes a predicative complement, it would be #11; denoting the direction of verb *get*, it would be OALD #18. Which one do I have to take? Is there any other view that I’ve missed?

Comment: I believe that it's #11 as you said. #18 requires moving from one position (place) to another.

Comment: I think I prefer 18. To me the word "get" has the same definition in "get on your hands and knees" and "get on the floor" and a closely related meaning to "get thee to a nunnery," where the latter two clearly fall under 18.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I myself was almost drawn to #11, but I've not found the case in dictionaries or grammar books. So I'm turning "on" to other side: on "used to show direction"[OALD, on.10](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/on)

Comment: I think it might be "get" #18, but it should be "on" #2 more than #10. Also, I might have to refresh my understanding of the term "linking verb", because different dictionaries seem to use it differently. For example, Oxford doesn't say that the verb *be* in *She's from Italy* and *The town is three miles away* is a linking verb; but [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/be) says that it is in *Baltimore is not far from Washington* and *Tom's from a small town in Canada*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OALD # 18 has the definition to move. - You could also say to get + where-to indication can mean go/come.
- Get on your hands and knees
means Get down/go down on your hands and knees, simply Kneel down.

Answer (score 1):

I see no very great difference between these two definitions:

> **11.** to reach a particular state or condition; to make somebody/something/yourself reach a particular state or condition
>
> **18.** to move to or from a particular place or in a particular direction, sometimes with difficulty; to make somebody/something do this

Definition **18** is just a special case of Definition **11** in which the “particular state or condition” which is achieved is location at or movement towards a particular place. The case you ask about, however, involves a posture rather than a place: *Get on your hands and knees* may be paraphrased “make yourself reach the condition of being on your hands and knees”.

It might very well be argued that Definition **11** is today the fundamental meaning of *get*: this sense underlies even the original sense of “obtain”, which may be paraphrased as “to reach or arrive at the state of possession of”. Definition **11** is remarkable in its generality, contemplating both non-agentive and agentive/causative uses.

Characterizing this as a *linking verb* is dubious to my mind. It is true that *get*  ascribes the state defined by its complement to its subject; but  *get* differs from the copula *be* in expressing not merely a state but a change of state. I’m not clear what  useful purpose is served by grouping *be* with verbs like *get* and *become*.